How is consent recorded in Entra ID and does it ever expire?
A user may consent to permissions for an application in Entra ID, thereby authorizing the application to perform actions on behalf of the user. Furthermore, admins may consent to permissions on behalf of all users in the tenant (admin permission grant).
I'm interested in the following, which I can't find an answer for in the linked docs:

How is consent recorded in Entra ID?
Does user- or admin consent ever expire? If not, how can a user or admin authorize the application to perform actions on behalf of the user only for a limited amount of time?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/permissions-consent-overview
